# google maps initialize can't see map variable when adding marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following initialization for a google map:

```
function initialize() 
    {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeControl: true, 
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
            },
            zoomControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            scrollwheel: true,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),
            mapOptions);
        }

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
    };
```

When trying to add the marker, I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined

How can I see this map or add a marker properly to the map?

Comment: The error I get is `Uncaught ReferenceError: myLatLng is not defined`.  Move the definition of the marker inside the `initialize` function (currently the `map` variable is local to the function). ([working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6ncm9dd/1/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you don't have a proper myLatLng position for your marker try  adding one  eg:    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.00, 10.00);

```
function initialize() 
    {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeControl: true, 
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
            },
            zoomControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            scrollwheel: true,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),
            mapOptions);
        }

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.00, 10.00);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
    };
```

Comment: it got rid of the error, but the marker doesn't show up.

Comment: The marker is the one inside the initialize() function?

Comment: If that was the problem the OP is having, ihe wouldn't see the map.